# calculate import-export

Tags: mysql, sql

Given a company table  `companylist` and a import-export table `trades`, I want to find the total exports and imports per country. I want to sort them by country name and print 0s instead of nulls if exports/imports are 0. All countries need to be present in output.

Companylist table =>

```
name    country
abc corp    congo
arcus t.g.  ghana
bob timbuktu
ddr ltd ghana
none at all nothingland
xyz corp    bubbleland
Y zap   timbuktu
```

trades table

```
id  seller  buyer   value
20120125    bob arcus t.g.  100
20120216    abc corp    ddr ltd 30
20120217    abc corp    ddr ltd 50
20121107    abc corp    bob 10
20123112    arcus t.g.  Y zap   30
```

The tables DDL -

```
create table if not exists companylist (name varchar(30) not null, country varchar(30) not null, unique(name));
    truncate table companylist;
create table if not exists trades (id integer not null, seller varchar(30) not null, buyer varchar(30) not null, value integer
not null, unique(id));
truncate table trades;
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('bob','timbuktu');
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('Y zap','timbuktu');
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('ddr ltd','ghana');
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('arcus t.g.','ghana');
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('abc corp','congo');
insert into companylist(name, country) values ('xyz corp', 'bubbleland');
insert into companylist(name,country) values ('none at all','nothingland');
insert into trades(id,seller,buyer,value) values (20121107,'abc corp','bob',10);
insert into trades(id,seller,buyer,value) values (20123112,'arcus t.g.','Y zap',30);
insert into trades(id,seller,buyer,value) values (20120125,'bob','arcus t.g.',100);
insert into trades(id,seller,buyer,value) values (20120216,'abc corp','ddr ltd',30);
insert into trades(id,seller,buyer,value) values (20120217,'abc corp','ddr ltd',50);
```

So far i have

```
select name, country, coalesce(sum(b.value),0) as export, coalesce(sum(c.value),0) as import
from companylist a left join trades b on a.name = b.seller
left join trades c on a.name = c.buyer
group by a.country order by a.country ASC;
```

I think this works, but does someone have a more elegant / better / different solution? I am learning sql so any feedback helps.

Comment: copy paste error oops - posted `companylist` DDL

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conditional aggregation is an option:

```sql
SELECT country, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.name = b.seller
                THEN b.value 
                ELSE 0
                END) as export, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.name = b.buyer
                THEN b.value 
                ELSE 0
                END) as import
FROM companylist a 
LEFT join trades b ON a.name IN (b.seller, b.buyer)
GROUP BY a.country 
ORDER BY a.country ASC;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52149365c57832464b3fa1cfa21d23cd)

PS. `companylist.name` makes no sense in output - it was removed.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend `union all` and `group by`:

```
select c.country, sum(sales) as exports, sum(buys) as imports
from countrylist c left join
     ((select t.seller as name, value as sales, 0 as buys
       from trades t
      ) union all
      (select t.buyer, 0 as sales, value as buys
       from trades t
      )
     ) bs
     on c.name = bs.name
group by c.country;
```

This should be much more efficient than Akina's solution which uses a function in the `on` clause (essentially an `or`).